# Can we add ACRA as maven repository instead of local one?

Tags: android-studio, acra

At the moment, I add ACRA in the Gradle via `compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')`.

Is there a way to use Maven repository (remote dependency library) and instead of `compile file` use a link such as `compile 'com.acra.blah.blah:version-of-acra'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your app dependencies closure replace
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')

with

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
```

Make sure that your repositories closure includes mavenCentral()

I should say, for completeness, that this is easy to find.  Go to http://mvnrepository.com and search for acra.  Select the version you want and then click on the gradle tab and there you will find the repo definition.